# Firefox: keyboard shortcut for 'Highlight all' in find bar

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

In firefox, I can't find any keyboard shortcut for the 'highlight all' feature in the Find toolbar at the bottom of the FF window. Is there a keyboard shortcut, and if not, what is the easiest way to assign one?

Edit: The answer below is for Windows, for doing the same on Mac OSX, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/71594/firefox-on-mac-osx-keyboard-shortcut-for-highlight-all-in-find-bar/71602#71602).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> works fine for me to toggle the Highlight All feature when the Find toolbar is displayed.

Comment: yep - the underlined 'a' in <kbd>Highlight all</kbd> indicates it's an <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcut :)

Comment: Ah, perfect. I hadn't noticed the underlines yet.

Comment: Huh. Ctrl-A works for me...

Comment: CTRL-A is the shortcut for "Select All", it doesn't trigger the "Highlight All" feature.

Comment: Alt+A works for me in Linux. Would be nice if also worked with '/' search.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox now uses <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to toggle the Highlight All feature when the Find toolbar is displayed.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>/</kbd> pops up quick find. A reg exp would be nice to have (for really long content). Although it'll take me more time to come up with the regexp than to browse the whole thing :p

For you regExp experts, there are some add-ons I think....... https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fastest-search/