# Firefox on Mac OS X: keyboard shortcut for ‘Highlight all’ in find bar

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I've previously [asked the question](https://superuser.com/questions/65498/firefox-keyboard-shortcut-for-highlight-all-in-find-bar) if there is a Firefox keyboard shortcut for the 'highlight all' feature in the Find toolbar at the bottom of the Firefox window. 
This was on Windows. On Mac there is no <kbd>Alt</kbd>-key logic, so <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> doesn't work.

So, is there any way to toggle 'highlight all' on Mac?

Comment: Does anyone know how to *disable* this shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can push <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in Mac OS X to do the same thing as <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in Windows.

Comment: It's actually command-a. Check the Edit menu when in doubt.

Comment: @NSD: For the Hilight All feature available in Firefox it's Control-A, to select all the text within a text box it is Command-A. The Hilight All feature shows all instances on a web page where the string is found.

Comment: Neat. I'll chalk that feature's necessity up as another reason not to use Firefox.

Comment: A shame it isn't indicated on the commands (like the underlining on Windows). Is this some common design to have Windows alt-accessible shortcuts to be replaced by a ctrl-equivalent?

Comment: When the search bar is opened, this (annoyingly) disables OS X’s Ctrl-a shortcut for moving the insertion point to the beginning of the line. Fortunately, the Firefox Ctrl-a shortcut for _Highlight All_ can be disabled by removing the _Highlight All_ button via `userChrome.css` – details see [Bug 672607 - Clash between Ctrl-a to "highlight all matches" in find-in-page and OSX's move cursor to start of line #c3](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672607#c3).

Comment: In FF 52 they changed the shortcut key to CTRL-L. Now I can't activate the shortcut with one hand any more (I only have one ctrl key, it'ss on the left).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> works too.

Long answer: There's a second set of keyboard shortcuts that works when the focus is in the Find toolbar's input (i.e. the text box that has focus when you show the Find toolbar).

<kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> : *Find the next occurrence of the phrase* (same as <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>)

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> : *Find the previous occurrence of the phrase* (same as <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>)

<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> : Toggle *Highlight all occurrences of the phrase* (same as <kbd>⌅ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)

Source: testing all key combinations I could think of, in Firefox 25 Aurora (might not work in previous versions; the Find toolbar was redesigned in Firefox 25, so some shortcuts may have changed or been added.)